# Blender 3.6 dae export window differs

Tags: export, collada

I have Blender v3.6.4 and according to [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/files/import_export/collada.html) official Blender manual link for v3.6 Collada (.dae file) export window should look like this:

[image]

But for some reason in real Blender v3.6.4 that window looks way different lacking many texture options compared to the manual version, see:
[image]

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here?!

You see: I am having trouble exporting textures when exporting to dae and those missing options seem like they could actually help to export those textures. Or are they accessible somewhere else? But why are they showing the export window options for .dae looks like that in their official online manual then? Mindboggling...

Comment: I see the same dialog. Suggest you report it as a bug via Help > Report a Bug in Blender including the link to the Blender manual section.

Comment: Investigating further, that manual page is the same right back to Blender 2.83 and every version of Blender that I've tried from 2.83 to 3.6.4 has the same options on the file selector. In fact the image in the manual appears to be a drop-down menu looking at the top of the image so I've no idea where that came from!

Comment: On the off chance that you are exporting model to SL then its,   1: in Blender's Collada export options panel > enable the Copy option. This saves a copy of the image texture to the same folder that you save the .dae file to.   2: In the SL mesh uploader > Upload Options tab > enable the Include textures option. This will tell the uploader to search for an image texture in the same folder as the .dae file and include it in the upload.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog 1.) have no clue what SL stands for, 2.) as you can clearly see **I HAVE COPY CHECKED** (!!) yet no texture (image) is exported with the .dae nor there is any reference inside the dae file for the texture (library_images tag is completely empty inside the dae file)